# API Routes: Get App by User or Get User's App

Tags: api-design, asp.net-mvc-web-api

We have a .Net WebApi 2 we've been working on for quite some time. As we refactor code, we started thinking of what might be a better practice: a) "to get an app by userid", or b) "to get a User's app"?

Currently, we have 2 controllers: `UsersController` and `ApplicationsController`. Each have a `GetById` where you pass in a known id of the object to get a specific object of that type.

On the `ApplicationsController` we also have another `GET` named `GetAppByUserId` with a route of `api/v1/app/user/{id}`.

Debating with co-workers, some of us believe this should probably be in the `UsersController` as `api/v1/user/{id}/app`.

What is the "standard", if there is one? We are ok adopting different standards than the loose standards we already have and want to understand different concepts others have so we can apply what we like in our case.

Thank you.

Comment: It's irrelevant from the client-side standpoint to be honest. However, it might help you out contextualize the operation. If you were navigating and operating over a user data, then option #2 seems a more natural choice. Note that, in the same context, option #1 can be misleading. Many will expect a User not an App.

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what "app for user" means. Are these predefined apps, and users may or may not have access to them? Or do you actually create new apps (how then is their functionality defined)? If the apps are predefined and just linked to users, you might consider an explicit `UserAppLink` kind of resource, or you might support an `api/v1/app?userId={userId}` type route which allows searching for apps that are linked to a user. Still you would need operations for creating and deleting those app links, of course.

Comment: Thanks! `Apps` are created by `Users` so they cannot exist without a `User`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per statement you provided
*As we refactor code, we started thinking of what might be a better practice: a) "to get an app by userid", or b) "to get a User's app"?*

If I simplified this statement then ultimately you want "Apps For particular userId". Also this statement also say that App will not exists without user.

In terms of REST approach this resource fit more like this.

```
api/v1/user/{id}/app
```

This will give operation like

- api/v1/user/{id}/app  -> Get List of apps of userId
- api/v1/user/{id}/app/{appid} -> Get specific app by user
- api/v1/user/{id}/app/{appId} -> with Put to update the app
- api/v1/user/{id}/app/{appId} -> with Delete to Delete app.
- api/v1/user/{id}/app     -> with post to create new app for user.

Comment: thank you! this was my and a few others ideas to change/update to. Others have reservations with .NET Web API where now the `UsersController` will have to host the `Application` data. since routes are currently defined as `/api/v1/[controller]`. We'll have to look into how we want to handle this as well.

Comment: If application is child of User then why do you need separate application controller. Also If naming is the problem then You can have usercontroller that host strictly user related api endpoint. While you can have UserApplicationsController that manager user application.